# xmodmap causes incorrect keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap

I used `xmodmap` to switch the Caps Lock and Ctrl keys on my Thinkpad X120e. The keys are swapped but this has caused keyboard shortcuts in several applications to stop working correctly. In Libre Office `Ctrl+Shift+s` no longer works (but `Ctrl+s` and `Ctrl+Shift+v` do). `Ctrl+Shift+S` is also broken in `emacs` (where I have it mapped to save as) and `Ctrl+N` and `Ctrl+Shift+N` have swapped purposes (new buffer and new frame). My `.xmodmap` file looks as follows:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_L
keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
add Lock = Caps_Lock
add Control = Control_L
```

I used the same file on my desktop (also running Debian Wheezy) and did not experience these problems.

Comment: Run `xev` from a terminal and press various keys in the xev window. When you enter `Ctrl+Shift+N`, as you press `N`, what appears in the terminal?

Comment: @Gilles Switching to xkb has actually solved the Ctrl+Shift+N problem but not the Ctrl+Shift+S problem. Pressing Ctrl+Shift+N yields:
`KeyPress event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0xaf, subw 0x0, time 5080983, (333,145), root:(942,446),
    state 0x5, keycode 57 (keysym 0x4e, N), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0e) ""
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0e) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False`

While Ctrl+Shift+S yields no event when the S is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79842/keybinding-issues-with-xmodmap-across-synergy#comment90348_79842) in an Askubuntu Q&A titled: [keybinding issues with xmodmap across synergy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79842/keybinding-issues-with-xmodmap-across-synergy).

*Excerpt*

> Do you run into the same problem if you use Xkb to swap
>   control/capslock? You should be able to do this through the keyboard
>   control panel application, or with setxkbmap. xmodmap has been known
>   to screw things up for xkb aware applications. – James Henstridge Nov
>   17 '11 at 1:16

Perhaps you should try using `setxbmap` instead of `xmodmap`?

I found this nice tutorial to get you started with `setxbmap` titled: [Extending the X keyboard map with xkb](http://madduck.net/docs/extending-xkb/), if you're interested.

I tried to find a list of what applications are XKB Aware but was unsuccessful. I did come across this document titled: [The X Keyboard Extension](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libX11/specs/XKB/xkblib.html). In this document there is mention of 3 classifications of applications,  in case you're interested.

Comment: I did try xkb but with the same results.

Comment: Can you share what you tried for xkb?

Comment: I used "setxkbmap -option ctrl:swapcaps".